# Como puedo calcular el tiempo medio de estos experimentos

Tags: java, calculo

tengo un metodo que se llama ordenarMatriz_2 y otro que se llama ordenarMatriz_2. A estos metodos les paso un int como parametro que tiene que ir de 32 a 8192. Quiero hacer que estos metodos se repitan 10 veces y que se calcule la media del tiempo que tardan. Tengo este codigo y no se como seguirlo:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int i = 32;
    int cont = 0;
    while (i <= 8192 && cont < 10){
        double tiempo1 = 0;
        ordenarMatriz_1(i);
        double tiempo2 = System.nanoTime() - tiempo1;
        double tiempo3 = 0;
        ordenarMatriz_2(i);
        double tiempo4 = System.nanoTime() - tiempo3;
        i = i*2;
        cont = cont+1;
    }

    //Como calculo la media?
    double media = 0

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puntos a tener en cuenta:

- Cuando sabes cuántas veces tienes que iterar, es mejor definir un bucle `for`. Como tienes que iterar dos variables, es mejor definir dos bucles `for`, de la forma que lo estas haciendo no tiene sentido, intenta analizar el flujo del código y te darás cuenta que no estas repitiendo el proceso 10 veces para cada tamaño de `i`
- Los tiempos que estas calculando no los estas almacenando en ningún sitio. Tienes que guardarlos en alguna estructura que te permita recuperarlos después, por ejemplo, un `ArrayList`. Una vez almacenado esos tiempos en la estructura auxiliar, puedes sobrescribir esta variable sin tener que declarar otras más.
- Para calcular la media, tienes que recuperar los tiempos de la estructura auxiliar  y dividirlos por el total de elementos.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    
    ArrayList<Double> tiempos1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> tiempos2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    double tiempo, sumatoria1 = 0, sumatoria2 = 0, media1 = 0, media2 = 0;
    int nExperimentos = 10;

    for (int i = 32; i <= 8192; i = i * 2){

            for (int j = 0; j < nExperimentos; j++){

            tiempo = System.nanoTime();
            ordenarMatriz_1(i);
            tiempo = System.nanoTime() - tiempo;
            tiempos1.add(tiempo);

            tiempo = System.nanoTime();
            ordenarMatriz_2(i);
            tiempo = System.nanoTime() - tiempo;
            tiempos2.add(tiempo);

        }
    }

    //Calulo la media para el primer método
    for (double d : tiempos1){
        sumatoria1 +=  d;
        media1 = sumatoria1 / nExperimentos;
    }

    //Calulo la media para el primer método
    for (double d : tiempos2){
        sumatoria2 +=  d;
        media2 = sumatoria2 / nExperimentos;
    }

}
```

---

*Edito par añadir funcionalidad de eliminar el max de los tiempos*

Para eliminar el máximo puedes hacerlo de las siguientes manera.

- La mejor forma en la que se ve, un bucle `for` donde recorres el `ArrayList` y lo comparas con el primero elemento, si es mayor, guardas ese valor, en caso contrario, el primer elemento será el mayor de todos.

```
double max = tiempos1.get(0);
for (double d : tiempos1){
    if (d > max)
        max = d;
}
tiempos1.remove(max);
```

- Usando Collections se puede hacer en una sola línea:

```
import java.util.Collections;
// ....
tiempos1.remove(Collections.max(tiempos1));
```

Comment: muchas gracias Fran me funciona bien y entiendo todo, si quisiera eliminar el maximo valor de los 10 tiempos que tengo en el arraylista lo hago en los for de abajo no?

Comment: No exactamente, te edito la respuesta para que lo veas.

Comment: gracias! funciona perfectoo